Does Salesforce Inspector bypass permission sets or profile restrictions when editing fields?
I am working with Salesforce and encountered an issue while using Salesforce Inspector. During testing, we noticed that even when we assign a Read-Only Permission Set for certain objects, users are unable to edit those fields through the Salesforce UI, but they can still edit the fields using Salesforce Inspector.
I have already verified that the Profile-level access is set to Read-Only, and the Permission Set should restrict editing, but the users can still modify data via Salesforce Inspector.
My question is:
Does Salesforce Inspector bypass the permissions set at the Profile or Permission Set level when editing field values? If so, is there a way to prevent this, or is this behavior expected in certain configurations?
I have searched the Salesforce documentation and forums but couldn't find a clear answer. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
I assigned a "Read-Only" Permission Set for specific objects to a user and ensured that the Profile also had "Read-Only" access for the same objects.
I verified the settings through the Salesforce UI to confirm that the user cannot edit the fields (as expected based on the permissions).
I tested the user access using Salesforce Inspector to see if they could edit the fields.
Expected Outcome: Based on the permission settings, I expected the user to be restricted from editing fields in both the UI and Salesforce Inspector.
Actual Outcome: While the UI correctly respects the "Read-Only" setting, the user is able to edit the fields in Salesforce Inspector, which bypasses the permission settings.

No, Salesforce Inspector does not bypass permission sets or profile restrictions when editing fields. Salesforce Inspector operates within the limits of the user's field-level security (FLS), object permissions, and sharing settings as determined by their profile and assigned permission sets.

Thank you so much for the reply but such issue is happening in the Salesforce Inpsector Advanced extention

I have tested this and noticed that the Salesforce Inspector is working in sync with field access provided through Profiles/ Permission Sets. I have created a user with Profile 'TestProfile'. Under Account object, I created 2 fields 'Test1' and 'Test2'. Under the Profile, I gave edit access to the field 'Test1' and read access to the field 'Test2'. I logged in as the user, opened an Account record, and verified that the User is able to edit the field 'Test1' and only view the field 'Test2'. I noticed same level of access when checked via Salesforce Inspector Advanced extention.
